# User-generated database entries in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am trying to do something in Rails and will admit that I'm no genius programmer, but I'm attempting to learn.

I want to create a database with user-generated entries of no specific number.  The best example of what I am trying to do can be illustrated by twitter.  I assume every time the user adds a new tweet it adds a row to the users tweet database.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to find resources to help me do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Teach me to code* has [a series](http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/creating-a-twitter-clone-in-rails-part-1/) on creating a Twitter clone in Rails. That might be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question. Have you tried some of the Rails tutorials? The main Ruby on Rails website has recently put up a bunch of new [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) that you might want to start with.

Comment: I apologize! I'll try to be more specific.  I want users to be able to log in to their account, and there will be a text field where they can enter a string and click "submit".  This string will be stored in a database as a row.  Ideally afterwards I will add some ajax so that it immediately appears below the text field.  Pretty much identical to how twitter works. Any guides in particular I should look at?

Thanks!

Comment: Ryan what you are describing is the most basic thing going on in Rails. There is no better answer than to learn Rails and I second thenduks that the rails guides are the best place to start.